# iOS sound plays while muted

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am making a learn-the-alphabet app for toddlers and I have encountered a problem with the sound output. Every sound the app plays when testing on my ipad has the same volume whether the device's sound is set at maximum or mute. In other words, the same sound level comes out regardless of the device's volume setting.

The code I use to play sounds is (using the A-sound as an example):

```
- (IBAction)aSpill:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"aLyd", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer here [AudioServicesPlaySystemSound Volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855874/audioservicesplaysystemsound-volume)
It explains that system sounds don't always use the system volume.

I suggest using AVAudioPlayer to play your sound instead.

Answer (score -1):

So from here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html

Try following the code using the below kind of code.

```
NSString *soundFilePath =
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"sound"
                                            ofType: @"wav"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
            [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL
                                                   error: nil];
[fileURL release];

self.player = newPlayer;
[newPlayer release];

[player prepareToPlay];
```

It is about halfway down the page.

Comment: The problem you are hitting is that some ways you access the volume will not go through the right channels creating what you are running into.

Comment: Wow seriously your just gonna down me and not leave a comment. Whoever you are that is lame.

Comment: Wasn't me! I tried the code @Tony, but xcode gives me errors on the last three lines of code. I have imported the AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h already.